# add_image_size() and uploading the exact size leaves 1x1 image in uploads

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, images

I've added an image size of `370x150` which works, but if I upload an image to those exact dimensions `get_post_thumbnail()` no longer works as expected. If I look into my uploads folder I'll have a `thumbnail`, `medium`, and `full` along with a `1x1`. I add the image size like so:

```
add_image_size('homepage_featured', array(370, 150));
```

and call that image like so:

```
the_post_thumbnail('homepage_featured');
```

which then pulls up the 1x1 image size. I could probably circumvent this by adding a conditional before my thumbnail call which tests if that size exists:

```
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'homepage_featured');
$thumbArr = explode('width="', $thumb);
if(!empty($thumbArr) && is_numeric($thumbArr[1][0]) && $thumbArr[1][0] >= 370)
    the_post_thumbnail('homepage_featured');
else
    the_post_thumbnail('full');
```

but that seems silly. Is this a normal thing or is it a problem with my custom theme? Is there a better way to test if a certain thumbnail size exists than the above method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Specifically note that the syntax is

```
add_image_size( $size, $width, $height );
```

What is likely happening is the array is resolved to false and defaulting to 0, as well as height.

As far as I know you can't have a 0x0 image, so it becomes 1x1 for that size.